# Getting Error: Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

i've tried nearly everything at other topics but i have the same problem in my rss reader app. How can i fix it?

i'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

i've updated AS to 2.12, java sdk latest version.

i've disabled instant run

i've tried cleanup project

i've installed HAXM

**In my app build.gradle file:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

dexOptions {
    incremental = true;
    preDexLibraries = false
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}


defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    applicationId "com.vbo.xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
         }
         }
dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'}
```

**in build.gradle project:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
```

}

**Android Manifest xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**complier --info:**

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. BUILD FAILED Total time: 2.574 secs Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).

**complier --stacktrace:**

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. Incremental java
>   compilation is an incubating feature. :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest
>   :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugResources
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prePackageMarkerForDebug
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug ProGuard, version 5.2.1
>   Reading program jar
>   [D:\Android\HerGun1Hadis\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
>   Reading library jar
>   [C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\lib\shrinkedAndroid.jar]
>   Preparing output jar
>   [D:\Android\HerGun1Hadis\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
>   Copying resources from program jar
>   [D:\Android\HerGun1Hadis\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\debug\jars\1\1f\combined.jar]
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   >     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>   >     non-zero exit value 1
> - Try: Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.   at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)    at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 1     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:54)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:57)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:173)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 70 more Caused by:
>     com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 1     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.transform(MultiDexTransform.java:148)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:178)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$3.call(TransformTask.java:174)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
>     ... 79 more Caused by:
>     com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>     org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with
>     non-zero exit value 1     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:43)
>     at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.createMainDexList(AndroidBuilder.java:1690)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.callDx(MultiDexTransform.java:244)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.computeList(MultiDexTransform.java:211)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.MultiDexTransform.transform(MultiDexTransform.java:144)
>     ... 82 more Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
>     Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe''
>     finished with non-zero exit value 1   at
>     org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:367)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.process.GradleProcessResult.assertNormalExitValue(GradleProcessResult.java:41)
>     ... 86 more
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 2.247 secs

Comment: Your question does not provide enough information for a multidex error. If you can post a more of the stack trace, that would be better. You seem to have "multiDexEnabled" declared twice.

Comment: i added stacktrace and other infos, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all make sure that in your Project No Duplicate library are there. Then Try below thing.

add this in your `build.gradle` file.

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer, i added the code but nothing changed.

Comment: @sanalmakina try to `clean` the project and `rebuild` it.

Comment: i did, it says build successful but when i click the run app button it says build failed with same error.

Comment: @sanalmakina go to `File >  Invalidate Caches/Restart ` and select `Restart`.

Comment: i did, but same error. Gradle Console Error: FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: @sanalmakina remove `multiDexEnabled true` you have add it `2 time`.

Comment: @sanalmakina also Change `buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"`

Comment: finally it works, i changed buildtoolsversion and invalidate c/r and run app. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you try to update to Java 8. Your stacktrace indicates that you are using Java 7 to build.

On https://developer.android.com/preview/setup-sdk.html it says that Java 8 is required:

> but you still need to update to JDK 8 to compile against the Android N platform, as described below.

and

> To compile your app against the Android N platform and use some tools with Android Studio 2.1, you need to install the Java 8 Developer Kit (JDK 8). So, if you don't already have the latest version, download JDK 8 now.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In `android/app/build.gradle` add:

```
defaultConfig {
  ...
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Step 2: Upgrade to AndroidX.