# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug

Tags: java, android

AS show me the below error, when i try of make project, o emulate:

i attach the image of AS, when show me the descripted error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [H:\Server...
```

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9NGu.jpg)

This is my build.gradle, i don't know it have any error

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "codingwithmitch.com.googlemapsgoogleplaces"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
    compile (group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpmime' , version: '4.3.5') {
        exclude module: 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient'}


    //Google play services
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
}
```

thnks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Error: Execution failed for task app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37906750/getting-error-execution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithmultidexlistfor)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Enable multidex on `build.gradle`file by changing its value to `true` -

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

         defaultConfig {
             minSdkVersion 14 //lower than 14 doesn't support multidex
             targetSdkVersion 22

             // Enabling multidex support.
             multiDexEnabled true
         }
}

dependencies {
    //need to add multidex dependency 
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Also you need to include this in your `Application` class:

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication  {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html)

Comment: I don't understand how this fixes `IOException: Can't write [H:\Server..`